# How much time has passed between Series 1 and 2 of Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, continuity

We watched the first episode of the second season last night and I'm a little unsure.  On the one hand Daenerys' story and the plot of Rob's crusade doesn't seem to have moved on very far at all.

On the other Bran is now much more independent, Joffrey has settled into his new role very quickly and Rob's wolf looked a LOT bigger.

How much time has passed between the two seasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much time at all. Apparently less than a month. The first season closes with Dany hatching her dragons, and the second season opens with Tyrion assuming his position as Hand of the King. According to [this fan-created spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj_uNZmcJaTddG9BVU5tRnJJTE5KcE5JRkFha1ZfNUE#gid=8) (**WARNING major spoilers for viewers who haven't read the books**) the hatching happened in the first month of year 299 AL, 20th day. Tyrion's stint as Hand started in the second month of the same year, 10th day.

As for the seemingly fast progression in the characters you mentioned, we need to remember that the show is an adaptation of a series of seriously thick books. There are a *lot* of story details that never get mentioned in the show due to time/budget constraints. For instance, Bran's new found freedom of movement using Hodor's back pack and his specially saddled pony galvanize his efforts to lead a new life.

Comment: Great answer - the one thing I'd comment is the comment about Tyrion... given this is set between series 1&2 if we're talking about anything other than his position as Hand can you edit it?

Comment: @Liath - I'm not sure I understand? Are you asking if we choose another incident as the start of season 2?

Comment: Oh. Haha. Not what I meant. Tyrion did rule as a defacto king at the time, so reign was a good word. But I'll change it.